# Transporting a Carbon MTB

Tags: car-rack

I took a punt and purchased a Mountain bike second hand, unseen (off our local equivalent to eBay).  It turns out it is a much higher spec bike than expected - including a carbon frame.

Until now I have used Thule 591 roof racks to carry my bike, which clamps the down tube. Can I carry a carbon bike using these racks, if not, what is the recommended way to carry it?

Comment: Have you checked what Thule's official word is? I'd be inclined to use a trailer hitch rack or put it inside the car, but that requires some car modification in some cases and installation + removal is a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the official recommendation, but the clamp *could* be problematic with a carbon DT.

Here's the thing, though: I don't think the clamp is strictly necessary. The purpose of the arm is to keep the bike from swaying laterally - you'll accomplish that as long as the arm is somehow attached to the frame. What I would do is put the DT in the clamp, but don't tighten the clamp: instead, use a rope or strap to tie the arm to the DT.

Another option: don't use the arm at all. Instead, use ratchet straps on either side to keep the bike upright. A lot of people do that when transporting motorbikes. This method seems more secure, but it might be difficult without a second set of hands.

[image]

Comment: There are trailer hitch racks which stand bicycles up vertically, but I don't think ratchet straps help in that case.

Comment: Hire plain trailer, lay down your bike and secure it with sth. Securing bike vertically with ratchet straps requires substantial force to be put on frame. With motorbikes it's unavoidable when you dont owe special wheel holder - but it ruins suspension.

Comment: @krzyski - Why would it have to be "substantial force"? You just have to tighten the straps until there's no slack.

Comment: @Batman - Nobody's talking about trailers. I just used this photo to illustrate the concept.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak what I wrote is invalid, when bike has no dampers. Otherwise, you need to squeeze it, just like on the photo of that Honda you posted. If not, bike is likely to "dive": under the straps.